# I have this code, and I'm trying to return the phrase in "", but it tells me that code "Cannot find 'age2' in scope". What can I do ? Thanks

Tags: swift

```
class Mercedes {
    
//  all the properties

    var model: String = "SLS300"
    
    var color: String = "gray"
    
    var automaticTransmission: Bool = true
    
    var age: Int? = 11

// here I have all the properties that I'm going to change in the future after calling the function
    
//     methods
    
    var transmission: String = "automatic"
    
    func specs() -> String {
        
        if automaticTransmission == true {
            
            transmission = "authomatic"
            
            guard let age2 = age else {
            
            return "\(color) Mercedes \(model) with mechanical transmission."
         }
            
        }
            else if automaticTransmission == false {
                
                transmission = "mechanical"
                
                guard let age2 = age else {
                    
                    return "\(color) Mercedes \(model) with \(transmission) transmission."
                }
                  
                
                
                
            }
        return "\(color) Mercedes \(model) with \(transmission) transmission \(age2) years old."
        }
            }
            
            // also tell me pls how to call the function
as Xcode does not show my specs() function here, ty
```

Comment: You declare it inside the if (and else) clause so it will not be available outside of that scope. Beside that, when will `automaticTransmission` be neither true or false? It looks to me like you need to re-think the flow inside that function

Comment: Why is it all so... double spaced? and crazily indented

Answer (score 0):

Hi @SergM1 first of all to call the function you need to instantiate the "Mercedes" class and then just call the function "specs" like the following code:

```
let mercedes = Mercedes()
let results = mercedes.specs()
```

As to why the compiler complaining its quite simple, any variable you declare within if/else statement will only ever be viable in it as @joakim Danielson mentioned.

Meaning age2 will not be accessible to you outside the if/else, what you can do is use the "age" parameter in the return instead of the "age2" and just provide default value like the following code:

```
 return "\(color) Mercedes \(model) with \(transmission) transmission \(age ?? 0) years old."
```

In default value you can provide any value you want as long as it is the same type as the variable you are defaulting.